# Three.js OrbitControls rotating up and down along whole screen attempts to go 360, but limited to 180

Tags: three.js, rotation

In OrbitControls.js There is a function:

```
function handleMouseMoveRotate( event ) {
    //console.log( 'handleMouseMoveRotate' );

rotateEnd.set( event.clientX, event.clientY );
rotateDelta.subVectors( rotateEnd, rotateStart );

var element = scope.domElement === document ? scope.domElement.body : scope.domElement;

// rotating across whole screen goes 360 degrees around
rotateLeft( 2 * Math.PI * rotateDelta.x / element.clientWidth * scope.rotateSpeed );

// rotating up and down along whole screen attempts to go 360, but limited to 180
rotateUp( 2 * Math.PI * rotateDelta.y / element.clientHeight * scope.rotateSpeed );

rotateStart.copy( rotateEnd );

scope.update();
```

}

I want to  rotating up and down along whole screen attempts to go 360, but limited to 180.but it can only be used OrbitControls.js.
Any help appreciated!!!!

Comment: Is it acceptable to use [`THREE.TrackballControls()`](https://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_trackball)?

Comment: I want to change the OrbitControls.js to achieve whole screen attempts to go 360  @ prisoner849